# display wordpress image from post

Tags: wordpress

What I am trying to do is create a portfolio for my client. So I have a custom post where she can add an artwork along with the images for the piece.

However, I want it to display in a slideshow and I can get the featured image to show up in the slideshow, but I to display all the images for that certain artwork in the slideshow, so someone could flip through them.

This is my current code:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></div>
<div class="item"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( 1 ); ?></div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

So I am grabbing the featured image, but need the rest of the images to show up in the slide show for that particular post.

I have tried using wp_get_attachment_image But how do I know what the ID is?e And wouldn't the ID need to be dynamic since every new artwork would be a different post with a different ID?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the loop, you can use

```
$images = get_children( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));

if ( count($images) ) {
    $size = 'thumbnail';  // medium, large
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $images as $id => $attachment ) {
        $title = esc_html( $attachment->post_title, 1 );
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size );
        $output .= '<a class="selector $size" href="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $id ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '">';
        $output .= '<img class="aligncenter" src="' . esc_url( $img[0] ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '" />';
        $output .= '</a>';
    }
   // Now do something with $output
   // which is collection of images wrapped with <a> from one post;
   // something like
   // <a href="..." title="..."><img src="..." alt="..." title="..." /></a>
   // <a href="..." title="..."><img src="..." alt="..." title="..." /></a>
}
```

From within the loop, the `$post->ID` will give you the post id, notice `'post_parent' => $post->ID,` in `get_children` function.

[Check on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).